# How do I paste text into chat in Rocket League?

Tags: rocket-league

I was playing with someone who doesn't speak much English, and using Google translate to communicate, manually typing in the translations. This is incredibly slow, as it's hard to remember foreign words.

I tried to use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste, but, it didn't work.

---

How do I paste text into chat? Alternatively, does [rocket-league](/questions/tagged/rocket-league) have a translator?

Comment: I cant find something that exactly says this, but I would guess CTRL+V to paste is probably a functionality that is disabled/not programmed in. It would be too easy to then have something dumb in your bin, and just spam it in chat. So my guess is that its not possible if it doesn't work outright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, after days of searching for an answer to this, I cannot find anything that *explicitly* states that pasting text is supported, or unsupported in a native way. However, the general consensus everywhere I land seems to be simply an inference that it's not possible.

With that, I wanted to create an application that would simulate typing so that you could replicate pasting the text. However, per the Rocket League [terms of service](https://www.psyonix.com/tou/), this would fall under "Prohibited User Conduct":

> (p) develops or allows any viruses, malware, adware, spyware, Trojan Horses, cancelbots, other automated “bots”, “auto players”, cheat utilities, spoofers, keyloggers, or other circumvention devices to be present on any machine used to access the Services; and/or to attempts to upload/utilize such devices against the Services;

As a result, I'm forced to give up my pursuit, and concur with the inferred consensus that it is simply not possible.

Comment: Well, I didn't get a solution, but thanks so much for the time you spent searching, here's the bounty.  If anyone ever finds a solution that allows me to paste the chat, I will naturally change the selected answer.  Thanks again for your time!  =)

Comment: @Millard no worries! I like helping others. I actually went through the effort of creating the application, but after reading the ToS, I had to abandon it. Didn't want all of that effort going to waste, so I decided to post an answer to summarize my efforts for you and future readers. :) Thanks for the bounty!